# Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Missing value for options: amount should be a number

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, stripe-payments, .net-5

```
const options = {
            mode: 'payment',
            amount: 1000,
            currency: 'inr',
            appearance, // Optional Style the Express Checkout Element
        };
        // Pass the appearance object to the Elements instance. // Optional Style the Express Checkout Element
        const elements = stripe.elements({
            options,
            fonts: [
                {
                    cssSrc: 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto',
                },
            ],
            // Specify the mode here
            mode: 'payment', // or 'setup' if you're setting up for future payments        
        });
```

[Express Checkout Element](https://stripe.com/docs/elements/express-checkout-element/accept-a-payment)

I have tried implementing the above code snippet in my checkout.js. Unfortunately, I'm encountering this error. Also, the express-checkout-element is not getting injected by Stripe.js into my form which is present in my Checkout.chtml. Finally, this is a MVC .Net 5 application trying to do Stripe Payments using Stripe Api and official docs documentation.

```
<!-- Display a payment form -->
<form id="payment-form">
    <!-- Create a container for the Payment Request Button -->
    <!--<div id="payment-request-button">-->
        <!-- The Payment Request Button will be inserted here -->
    <!--</div>-->
    <div id="express-checkout-element">
        <!-- Mount the Express Checkout Element here -->
    </div>
    <!--<div id="card-element">-->@*Stripe.js injects the Card Element*@<!--</div>-->
    <div>&nbsp;</div>
    <button id="submit">
        <div class="spinner hidden" id="spinner"></div>
        <span id="button-text">Pay now</span>
    </button>
    <p id="card-error" role="alert"></p>
    <p class="result-message hidden">
        To see the Payment status, check the results in your
        <a href="" target="_blank">Stripe dashboard.</a> Refresh the page to pay again.
    </p>
</form>

@section Scripts{
    <script src="https://js.stripe.com/v3/"></script>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?version=3.52.1&features=fetch"></script>
    <script src="~/js/checkout.js" defer></script>
}
```

Tried commenting out options when defining elements variable.
Tried reaching out to Stripe support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to update your js code to match the following:

```
const options = {
  mode: 'payment',
  amount: 1099,
  currency: 'inr',
  // Customizable with appearance API.
  appearance: {
     theme: 'stripe',
     variables: {
        fontFamily: 'Ideal Sans, system-ui, sans-serif'
     }
  },
};

// Set up Stripe.js and Elements to use in checkout form
const elements = stripe.elements(options);
```

Comment: This helped me solve this problem. I'm getting a new warning asking me to register domains for payment methods. [https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/pmd-registration) I can't find in the documentations the recommended domains and subdomains for Google Pay, Apple Pay or Paypal.

Comment: There is no recommended domains in particular, just register your own domain in order to accept wallet payments.